# cordova is not a valid task ionic v1 angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

[while adding cordova to ionic version1 project I'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57YBn.png)

Pls Help that build process for angularjs ionic v1 project

Build steps for angularj ionic v1 project

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to upgrade your project to a newer version of ionic and use Capacitor instead of Cordova, but for your case, you should install Cordova as a global package using npm

`npm install -g Cordova`

because of the outdated version that you use, you should install a compatible version of Nodejs and ionic Cli.

after installing Cordova as npm package add Cordova to your project using:

```bash
cordova platform add android
```

and build it:

```bash
ionic cordova build android
```